# Javac -d flag cant create folder

Tags: java

*Why javac -d classes Main.java cant create folder classes?
I try like this -*

[image]

Comment: Well all you've got to do is create that one folder. `javac` will create the package hierarchy within it. Checking for presence helps prevent typos...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's clearly said that **the directory must already exist; javac will not create it.**

> -d directory
>
> Set  the destination directory for class files. The directory must already exist; javac will not create it. If a class is
>   part of a package, javac puts the class file in a subdirectory
>   reflecting the package name, creat‐
>                ing directories as needed. For example, if you specify -d /home/myclasses and the class is called com.mypackage.MyClass, then
>   the class file is called /home/myclasses/com/mypackage/MyClass.class.
>                If -d is not specified, javac puts each class files in the same directory as the source file from which it was generated.
>
> Note: The directory specified by -d is not automatically added to your user class path.